# How to decode JSON object with Rust keyword attribute name?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I was wondering if it is possible to decode a JSON object in Rust that has an attribute name which is also a Rust keyword. I am working with the `rustc-serialize` crate and my struct definition looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct MyObj {
  type: String
}
```

The compiler throws an error because `type` is a keyword:

```rust
error: expected identifier, found keyword `type`
src/mysrc.rs:23     type: String,
                           ^~~~
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the original data can't be changed to avoid the conflict?

Comment: yes, it would be best if i didn't have to change the source data. I guess maybe creating a new struct field with a different name and writing a custom `impl Decodable` is the only way?

Comment: I can see either manually implementing it or using `Json::from_str` and then poking into its result value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde) crate. It supports renaming of fields [since February 2015](https://github.com/erickt/rust-serde/pull/22)

Your example could then look like this:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    #[serde(rename = "type")] 
    type_name: String
}
```

Comment: Seems like exactly what i was looking for. It says it does some lookahead, do you know if it is possible to parse an attribute that could be one of a few different types? so a field called msg could be either a JSON string or an array.

Comment: That is one of the main reasons serde was invented, because the old deserializer couldn't read an enum without having read a tag beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without `serde`'s field renaming by using [raw identifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/compatibility/raw_identifiers.html). By adding `r#` in front of an identifier, a keyword name can be used.

### Using [`rustc-serialize`](https://crates.io/crates/rustc-serialize)

```rust
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct MyObj {
    r#type: String
}
```

### Using [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde)

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    r#type: String
}
```

Note that `rustc-serialize` is deprecated in favor of `serde`.